# Math.atan() returning input

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

I'm having a problem with Math.atan returning the same value as the input.

```
public double inchToMOA( double in, double range){
        double rangeIn = 36*range;
        double atan = (in / rangeIn) * -1.0;
        double deg = Math.atan(atan);
        double moa = deg * 60;
        return moa;
    }
```

I had this all in one line, but I broke it down into different variables to see if I could find out why it wasn't working. if in = -10 and range = 300, then atan is about -.00094. The angle should be about -.053 degrees, but math.atan is returning -.00094, the same as the input.

Is my number too small for math.atan?

Comment: The code you have here seems right; are you sure that the error isn't someplace else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inverse tangent is described here:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangent.html

I don't think your argument is the problem here.

You realize, of course, that computer trig functions deal in radians rather than degrees, right?

Comment: I didn't know it was in radians, that would explain it thanks!

Comment: @Matt - you must have skipped those high-school maths classes :-)

Comment: Why would I skip them? A guy's gotta get some sleep somewhere! :) Sometimes I get a little baked after hours and hours of writing code... "It's working on the !@#!$ calculator why not on the... oh..."

Answer (score 1):

It might just be.  If you look at the strict definition of the tangent function in mathematics what you see if that `tan(x) = sin(x)/cos(x)`  for small values of "x"

```
lim x->0, sin(x) = x
lim x->0, cos(x) = 1
```

hence, you could see that `lim x->0, tan(x) -> x` meaning that it's inverse, arctan, returns the value it is given.  As to the numerical accuracy of Math.atan I would think that the authors had gone to great lengths to ensure it's numerical accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with `Math.atan`.  Its value is nearly 1:1 linear, intersecting the origin, for inputs close to zero.  So the closer you are to zero the less change from the input there will be.

Comment: according to my calculator, it should be returning -.053. atan (-10 / 10800) = atan -.00094 = -.053

Comment: @Matt is your calculator set to degrees?  0.053 degrees is appoximately 0.0009 radians.

Comment: Oops, if it is radians it wouldn't change much . Thanks!